# Working with an existing Solr index in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm writing a Ruby on Rails app that would replace an old application. We have an existing Solr service running which I wish to integrate in our new RoR app. What is the best way to approach this? From what I've learned so far online, Sunspot is more suitable for automatically indexing Ruby object in Solr not the other way around (integrating an already existing index) ?!

Answer (score 1):

you can check upon [rsolr](https://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr), on which sunspot is based upon, which will allow you to query on an existing index.